# beautifulsoup not parsing xml tag correctly but lxml is

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

The following code is not working as expected:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/einfo.fcgi?retmode=xml&db=pmc'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
links =  soup.find_all('link')
```

the `links` result produces a bunch of ` tags (only some shown):

```
<link/>
<name>pmc_sra</name>
<menu>SRA</menu>
<description>Links to SRA</description>
<dbto>sra</dbto>
<link/>
<name>pmc_structure</name>
<menu>Structure Links</menu>
<description>Published 3D structures</description>
<dbto>structure</dbto>
<link/>
```

Printing `response.text` shows (only partial print shown):

```
<Link>
    <Name>pmc_sra</Name>
    <Menu>SRA</Menu>
    <Description>Links to SRA</Description>
    <DbTo>sra</DbTo>
</Link>
<Link>
    <Name>pmc_structure</Name>
    <Menu>Structure Links</Menu>
    <Description>Published 3D structures</Description>
    <DbTo>structure</DbTo>
</Link>
<Link>
```

Importantly, each `Link` tag contains other tags, whereas beautifulsoup is suggesting the link tags stand alone.

If I try `lxml` directly, I get the correct link tags:

```py
from lxml import etree
#root = etree.fromstring(response.text)
root = etree.fromstring(response.text.encode('utf-8'),parser=etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))

for link in root.iter("Link"):
    etree.dump(link)
```

produces:

```
<Link>
    <Name>pmc_sra</Name>
    <Menu>SRA</Menu>
    <Description>Links to SRA</Description>
    <DbTo>sra</DbTo>
</Link>

<Link>
    <Name>pmc_structure</Name>
    <Menu>Structure Links</Menu>
    <Description>Published 3D structures</Description>
    <DbTo>structure</DbTo>
</Link>
```

Note, I was getting an error with the simpler `etree.fromstring` call. Perhaps the problem with BeautifulSoup is an encoding problem?

I'm using what I think is the newest BeautifulSoup (4.8.2) and LXML (4.5.0) in Python 3.7.6

Comment: try "lxml-xml" for your parser.

Comment: From the parsers section of the BeautifulSoup docs: `xml’s HTML parser BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml") `.

Comment: @AMC as referenced in my answer, that uses the lxml library strictly for parsing HTML.  You need to use lxml-xml.

Comment: @David Sorry if my comment wasn't clear, I meant to point out that `"lxml"`, which OP is currently using, is for parsing HTML, not XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

I believe the problem is with using "lxml" versus "lxml-xml".  If I am correct, Beautiful Soup is trying to parse your XML as HTML and mangling the data therefore.

Comment: I've looked at that page numerous times and completely spaced that "lxml" is NOT xml!?!? That almost seems like a bug to me, although perhaps there is a reason to keep that behavior? Of course I would have gotten away with it too if it weren't for a "link" tag, which is self-closing in html! Thanks.

Comment: @Jimbo Unfortunately most roads to BeautifulSoup lead from trying to parse bad HTML so the default parser isn't "lxml-html".   As soon as I saw your mangled link tags I knew that was the problem but I had always assumed BS did some sort of magic behind the scenes and not required an explicit "no seriously I want to parse XML"  via "lxml-xml".

Comment: Yeah, I'm really curious if that's useful for anyone to have BeautifulSoup parse xml as html. I can understand if you pass in a partial page, and thus BeautifulSoup may not be sure what it is seeing, but when the opening tag is literally `<xml`, forcing all tags to take on html behavior seems strange. Oh well, it only took roughly 30 minutes to switch from lowercase tags to Uppercase tags! Thanks again.